# SQL- UNION ALL a large number of tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large number of tables (some thousands) containing similar data. I would like to run some reports from these. The table names are similar, so I can get a list of table names.

I will likely merge these tables in the future, should be trivial once the select works.

```
--Getting a list of all tables 
select TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'TableNamePrefix%'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

To combine data, I can use UNION ALL, but not sure about how to set up the WHILE/cursor so that the list does not need to be constantly updated.

Something like

```
SELECT * FROM TableNamePrefix00001
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TableNamePrefix00002
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TableNamePrefix00003
--And so on for all tables in the list
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Use Dynamic SQL

Comment: Merge them first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using your pattern on table name - i got somewhere with

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);

select @SQL =  COALESCE(@SQL , '') + 'SELECT * FROM [' +  TABLE_NAME + ']  UNION ALL ' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME LIKE '%employeedet%';

SELECT @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 11);

print @SQL;
```

Comment: Change the SELECT line to the below to avoid a trailing UNION ALL:  `select @SQL =  COALESCE(@SQL + ' UNION ALL ' , '') + 'SELECT * FROM [' +  TABLE_NAME + ']'`

Comment: I ended up using this one, with EXEC rather than print due to character limit. Some of the other comments would be fine solutions also.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with Dynamic SQL

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) =''
Select @SQL = @SQL +'Union All Select * From '+Table_Name+' ' 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'TableNamePrefix%'
  ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
Set @SQL = Stuff(@SQL,1,10,'')
Exec(@SQL)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 'select * from  '+TABLE_NAME +' union all'
FROM
 INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%chd%'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

remove last union all

Answer (score -1):

All these tables have the same data types and number of columns, because if this not the case then you will not be able to use UNION sentences, however, it's very strange to merge all the information in this way, could you put some examples to clarify it.

Comment: at a guess, there has been a design where data of a certain category has been hived off into tables just for that data, e.g. AccountsJan2000, AccountsFeb2000,...  I have seen that done before - hence 'I will likely merge these tables in the future'

Comment: Yeah, pretty much that case. Many tables with similar data where a single table would have done the job.

Comment: Please do not second-guess why the OP is asking their question. They've explained what the situation is and are aware that the tables ought to be merged. There are various reasons why a database might contain tables with similar schemas: that's why `UNION` and `UNION ALL` exist.