# View columns from tables where name like 'ENG_Parameters_%'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I am trying to create a SQL View that will load columns:

```
[item],[manufacturer_item],[symbol],[footprint]
```

from any table that matches the name ENG_Parameter_%.

I need to leave it generic because, at any point in time, ENG_Parameter_% might have new or removed tables, so I cannot just hard-code any table names.

Is there a SQL command that could be made to generate this?

Comment: Sounds like you have a real data modeling problem if you want to be joining in tables based on wildcards.  If this is a real need, then you will need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: When you need dynamic table names you're probably doing something wrong. You should put all data into one table.

Comment: @somega This was my original concept; however, due to the number of columns that are created, this is not possible as it would destroy the performance of the server it is held on and would easily exceed the 1024 column limit.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into that and see if I can't figure it out.

Comment: I asked this same one a few years back and got some good responses- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384003/sql-union-all-a-large-number-of-tables

Of course the correct answer is to reconsider your design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@OwlsSleeping](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7354796/owlssleeping) answer ([StackOverflow SQL-UNION ALL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384003/sql-union-all-a-large-number-of-tables)), this ended up with exactly what I needed:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

select @SQL =  COALESCE(@SQL , '') + 'SELECT [item],[manufacturer_item],[symbol], 
[footprint] FROM [' +  TABLE_NAME + ']  UNION ALL ' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME LIKE 'ENG_Parameters_%'

SELECT @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 11)
exec sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic sql to create the views:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(2000);

SET @SQL=N' SELECT
  ''CREATE VIEW [vw'' + t.name + '']
  AS
  SELECT [item],[manufacturer_item],[symbol],[footprint] 
  FROM ['' + t.name + '']'' AS sql_for_view
  FROM sys.columns c
  INNER JOIN sys.tables t
  ON c.object_id=t.object_id
  WHERE c.name LIKE ''ENG_Parameter_%''';

exec sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: it is the table name. The sample uses vw + table name as view name.

Comment: Did you even try it? It is an answer to the question. But even you don't have the environment, you can still run it. It just  return  no rows.

Comment: t is the alias of sys.tables. No variables in the query.

Comment: Okay, so after some modifications to this response, I was able to get it to give me a list of individual CREATE VIEWs, however I actually need to have a Single VIEW that has a union of all the tables returned