# get all the rows from a database having tables with different number of columns but one common column where column name = some value

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get all the rows present in a database where columnname='some value'.
Tried this:

```
declare commands cursor for 

    select 'select * from '+name +' where acc='+ CHAR(39)+'2375'+ CHAR(39) from sys.tables
    declare @cmd varchar(max)

open commands
fetch next from commands into @cmd
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin
  exec(@cmd)
  fetch next from commands into @cmd
end

close commands
deallocate commands
```

But the above script gives me rows from just one table as other other tables have different number of columns.

I need resulting data like this:
**id acc  m1    m2   age**  
2  7455 null  null 40   
3  7455 c1    null null  
4  7455 c2    d2   null  
2  7455 null  d2   36

Each row is from a different table having same column 'acc'.Trying to execute it in Azure SQL database

Comment: Are you looking for the list of tables which contain a particular column name?  Or are you looking for the values in those columns?

Answer (score 0):

Your script is throwing the rows of every table in sys.table but I think you only can see the result of the last table.

You can try to use Union All but you will have to choose the specific columns you want.

[Check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384003/sql-union-all-a-large-number-of-tables)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the place to get started is with the list of tables which contain a particular column name.  This SQL gets the names and object_id's of tables containing a column named 'acc' and inserts them into the temp table @names

```
declare
  @columnname           nvarchar(2048)='acc';

/*store a list of table names in a temp table */
declare
  @names      table(col_object_id            int,
                    col_tablename            nvarchar(2048) unique not null);

/* get the name of every table with column name */
insert @names(col_object_id, col_tablename) 
select t.[object_id], t.[name] 
from 
  sys.tables t
  join
  sys.columns sc on t.[object_id]=sc.[object_id]
where
  sc.name=@columnname;
```