# How to UNION ALL tables with tablename satisfying condition in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I can unify two tables via:

```
select * from project.dataset.ourtable1
union all
select * from project.dataset.ourtable2
```

But what if I have thousands of tables, and I want to unify all which have name starting with `ourtable`?

I can get all such tables via:

```
select table_id from project.dataset.__TABLES__
where starts_with(table_id,'ourtable')
```

which returns a column of tables with `table_id` starting with `ourtable`.

**How do I perform `union all` on all of them?**

To rephrase the question: I am looking for the equivalent of

```
select * from project.dataset.ourtable1
union all
select * from project.dataset.ourtable2
union all
.
.
.
union all
select * from project.dataset.ourtable9999
```

in BigQuery.

---

A similar thread: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384003/sql-union-all-a-large-number-of-tables), but it is for SQL-Server, not BQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [wildcard](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables):

```
select * from `project.dataset.ourtable*`
```